# Allowing External Users to Communicate with Internal service

Tags: windows, wcf, authentication, ssl, active-directory

I am having issues exposing information that internal users can access to users that regularly travel outside of our internal network.

The way things work now is that we have a program that accesses a WCF Service which is hosted on a public facing secured web site. When a user is using our internal network, the service works fine. However, as soon as the user goes out of network (say to a hotel) they being getting 401: not Authorized errors.

Sometimes with the following underlying causes

1. Request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme ‘Anonymous’. The header received was ‘NTLM, Negotiate’
2. The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request
3. The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

There is a workaround that I am not too entirely thrilled with with, which is manually adding the credentials (domain/username with password) to the Windows Credential Manager, which works until the point where the Credentials are cleared and then the process starts again. When this happens, users can navigate to the services in their browser and successfully consume them in the program.

This is the Binding we are using for the WCF Service

```
     <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">

      <security mode="Transport">

        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />

      </security>

    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

It seems based on the Windows Credential Manager fix that we should be able to use the Users Active Directory account to manage the authentication for this service.

I was just wondering if it is possible to deploy a service that will allow access for remote users based on them having successfully signed into an account with our domain.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing internal endpoints directly to the outside world it not a good practice. You always use an external Bus, so you don’t need to open any firewall ports. For example, you can better use the Azure Service Bus, it’s more secure and reliable then allowing direct connections to your internal network.

**Connect on-premises applications to the cloud**

Service Bus Relay solves the challenges of communicating between on-premises applications and the outside world by allowing on-premises web services to project public endpoints. Systems can then access these web services, which continue to run on-premises from anywhere on the planet.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/